# How can I add a list item if another list item has a particular class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an autoplay tab class current for the active tab, which means when the tab is active the list item has a class named current.

Now I want to to add different class to first child `<li class="li-animation"></li>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

  if ($('li.stp-1').hasClass('current')) {
    $('.li-animation').addClass('hover-1');
  } else {
    $('.li-animation').removeClass('hover-1');
  }

  if ($('li.stp-2').hasClass('current')) {
    $('.li-animation').addClass('hover-2');
  } else {
    $('.li-animation').removeClass('hover-2');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
  $(function () {
    var boxes = $(".HWBlock"),
      tabs = $(".tablinks");

    function showTabContent() {
      return boxes.queue("tabs", $.map(boxes, function (el, curr) {
        return function (next) {
          boxes.hide() // hide `.box` elements
            .add(tabs) // add `.tabs` to current selector
            .removeClass("current") // remove `.current` class
            .filter(el) // current `.box` element
            .fadeIn(150) // fade in current `.box` element
            .add(tabs.eq(curr)) // add `.tabs` at index `curr` to selector
            .addClass("current") // add `current` `className` to selector
            .end() // end current selection at `.boxes` selector
            .delay(5000, "content") // set, delay `"content"` queue 5000ms
            .dequeue("content") // dequeue `"content"` queue
            .promise("content") // at completed promise of `"content"` queue
            .then(next) // call next function in `"tabs"` queue
        }
      }))
        .dequeue("tabs") // dequeue `"tabs"` queue
        .promise("tabs") // at completed promise of `"tabs"` queue
        .then(showTabContent); // call `showTabContent` recursively
    }
    showTabContent();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="d-md-flex wow fadeInDown">
  <li class="li-animation"></li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-1">stp-1</li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-2">stp-2</li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-3">stp-3</li>

</ul>
<div class="how-works-text wow fadeInUp">
  <div class="HWBlock step-1" id="step-1">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="HWBlock step-2" id="step-2">
    <p>test 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="HWBlock step-3" id="step-3">
    <p>test 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly when do you want to add another class?

Comment: when the li that has class stp-1 have class current i want to add class hover-1
when the li that has class stp-2 have class current i want to add class hover-2

Comment: `now i[sic] want to to add different class to first child` - and what's stopping you?  What's the actual issue?  Do you have a question? (other than "how")?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you're using? I don't see a big issue with it at a first glance.

Comment: i want when the li that has class stp-1 have class current i want to add class hover-1 and 
when the li that has class stp-2 have class current i want to add class hover-2

Comment: Please show the code where you add the class "current".

Comment: @johannesH the code not working 
the class dont get added to `<li class="li-animation"></li>`

Comment: Your code currently runs once, when the page loads, and never again.

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey
class "current" get add automatic to `<li class="tablinks stp-1">stp-1</li>` and `<li class="tablinks stp-2">stp-2</li>` and `<li class="tablinks stp-3">stp-3</li>`
every 5 seconds

Comment: @Heretic Monkey yes that's another problem

Comment: now you can see that `if` not working

Comment: Right, so you need to run your code after the "current" class is added (`.addClass("current")`). I suggest putting it into a function, then adding `.then(functionName)` right under the line that adds the "current" class.

Comment: @amine please update your question so we don't have to read all the comments to gather the pertinent info or just declare it resolved if HM resolved the issue.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey  i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an absolute guess on what may work, based on the very limited information you've given us in your question and in the comments. This is based solely on my knowledge of the effects queuing functionality of jQuery, which is limited.

I also took the liberty of using `toggleClass` to reduce the length of the code adding or removing the "hover-*" classes to the element with the "li-animation" class.

I also added some simple CSS for the classes being added so it was easier to visualize if the code works or not.

```js
function addHoverClasses() {
  $('.li-animation').toggleClass('hover-1', $('li.stp-1').hasClass('current'));
  $('.li-animation').toggleClass('hover-2', $('li.stp-2').hasClass('current'));
  $('.li-animation').toggleClass('hover-3', $('li.stp-3').hasClass('current'));
}

$(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
  $(function () {
    var boxes = $(".HWBlock"),
      tabs = $(".tablinks");

    function showTabContent() {
      return boxes.queue("tabs", $.map(boxes, function (el, curr) {
        return function (next) {
          boxes.hide() // hide `.box` elements
            .add(tabs) // add `.tabs` to current selector
            .removeClass("current") // remove `.current` class
            .filter(el) // current `.box` element
            .fadeIn(150) // fade in current `.box` element
            .add(tabs.eq(curr)) // add `.tabs` at index `curr` to selector
            .addClass("current") // add `current` `className` to selector
            .queue(function (next) {
              addHoverClasses();
              next();
            })
            .end() // end current selection at `.boxes` selector
            .delay(5000, "content") // set, delay `"content"` queue 5000ms
            .dequeue("content") // dequeue `"content"` queue
            .promise("content") // at completed promise of `"content"` queue
            .then(next) // call next function in `"tabs"` queue
        }
      }))
        .dequeue("tabs") // dequeue `"tabs"` queue
        .promise("tabs") // at completed promise of `"tabs"` queue
        .then(showTabContent); // call `showTabContent` recursively
    }
    showTabContent();
  });
});
```

```css
.current { border: 1px solid green; }
.hover-1 { background-color: blue; }
.hover-2 { background-color: red; }
.hover-3 { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="d-md-flex wow fadeInDown">
  <li class="li-animation"></li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-1">stp-1</li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-2">stp-2</li>
  <li class="tablinks stp-3">stp-3</li>

</ul>
<div class="how-works-text wow fadeInUp">
  <div class="HWBlock step-1" id="step-1">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="HWBlock step-2" id="step-2">
    <p>test 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="HWBlock step-3" id="step-3">
    <p>test 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```